# need help in proving $\sum_{p^n \leq x, n\geq 2} \frac{\log p} {p} =O(1)$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This question is a part of merten's formula and I am struck on this particular equation and need help.

> Prove that $\sum_{ p^n \leq x, n\geq 2 } \frac{\log p} {p} =O(1)$, where $O$ is big O notation.

I am sorry but I am unable to get any intution, although question seem to be easy and maybe that's why no explanation is given.

A hint would be sufficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, this looks like it would be an unbounded sum.  Is there an exponent missing on the sum term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked to prove that
$$ \sum_{p^n \leq x, n \geq 2} \frac{\log p}{p} = O(1). $$
This is false.

The sum is bounded below by
$$ \sum_{\substack{p \\ p^2 \leq x}} \frac{1}{p}
= \sum_{p \leq \sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{p}
\gg \log \log (\sqrt {x}).$$

It is necessary to go about your proof of Merten's formula in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by induction easily.

1. For n=2 it is more or less clear.
2. Assume it is true for some n.
3. Now when we have n+1, the sum can be divided into two sums - one over $p^{n}\leq x$ (and it is O(1) from induction assumption) and the second one for $p^{n}>x$.
   Using Prime Number Theorem, how many prime numbers can You have in interval $[p^{n},p^{n+1}]$?